# Encriptado y desencriptado AES/ECB/PKSC S5Padding

Tags: nodejs

Actualmente estoy queriendo implementar un cifrado y decifrado del mismo, con las siguientes condiciones:
La clave secreta se debe convertir a SHA-256 y se debe tomar los primeros 16 bytes para cifrar
El valor en la propiedad del mensaje JSON debe estar en Base64/UTF8.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo, funciona, pero no realiza la encriptacion correctamente.

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
module.exports = {
  aesEncrypt: aesEncrypt,
  aesDecrypt: aesDecrypt,
};

let key = "";//Omitida por seguridad

const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(key.slice(0, 16));
const keyhash = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)

function aesEncrypt(content) {
  const parsedkey = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyhash);
  const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyhash);
  const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content, parsedkey, {

    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  });
  return encrypted.toString();
}
function aesDecrypt(word) {
  var keys = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyhash);
  let base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(word);
  let src = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(base64);
  let decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(src, keys, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
  });
  return decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}

const text_to_encrypt = "755";
const result = aesEncrypt(text_to_encrypt);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado que tal,

Bueno para comenzar:

1.-La extracción de los primeros 16 bytes de la clave no es antes si no después que tienes el hash.

2.-El hash que genera no debes convertirlo en base64 debe ser así:

```
const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(key);
KeyHash = hash.slice(0,16)
```

3.-No debes parsear el key ya con lo anterior te funciona para encriptar

```
encrypt(key:string,str:any){
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(this.algorithmData, key, null);
    return Buffer.concat([cipher.update(str), cipher.final()]).toString('base64');
}
```

4.- El vector de inicialización no es necesario puedes colocarlo en null como en el ejemplo anterior

Nota: La encriptación debe ser binario luego la codificas en base64

Espero te haya ayudado

Saludos